# Javascript html canvas organise lines to prevent overlap

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on some logic for a labelling exercise.

[image]

I want to connect every red dot to a blue dot, but without the lines overlapping. (not as shown below)

[image]

I have a jsfiddle that generates dots and connects them here

https://jsfiddle.net/s1u7okd5/

```
enter code here
```

Red dots can vary, obviously, blue dots are fixed. I don't need someone to do the work for me, but I could do with some direction.

Questions:

1: I assume it's always possible to find a solution where the lines don't overlap (ignoring thickness of drawn line). Is this true?

2: I hoping to avoid a brute force approach. Is this possible?

Comment: Given a fair quantity of required line connections, it will quickly become impossible to avoid overlaps. What do you intend if overlaps are impossible to avoid?

Comment: @markE can you demonstrate this? In my opinion, if you link each red point to the nearest blue point, you avoid line crossing.

Comment: @DavideVisentin. Sure, even assuming one red dot for each blue dot there are intersecting combinations. Red dots roughly in 4 corners of square with another red dot in the center of the square. Red dots roughly in 3 horizontal rows -- the center row is "blocked" from the blue dots. Ditto with 3 vertical columns. Or cluster red dots (eg put many of them in/around Jupiter). I have no idea of the dataset, but random chance can produce these intersecting patterns.

Comment: @markE - I tried the combinations you suggested but always managed to find a solution without overlaps. Not saying you're wrong as I'm not 100% certain myself, but I'm leaning towards the conclusion that there is always a solution. [here is a mockup] (https://postimg.org/image/4ioheztap/)

Comment: @Ben.  [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/2016-09-03_23-30-35.png) is a theoretical problematic configuration -- see the clustered green dots on Jupiter. These theoretical combinations would cause the lines to intersect, but if the combinations don't occur in your datasets then you should be fine.

Comment: @markE. Thanks mark. I've connected the lines up in your example [here](https://postimg.org/image/kkyom8kkn/) & 
[here](https://postimg.org/image/m1a74dnhj/).
I understand that the thickness of the lines and dots may make lines look intersecting (which is okay) but still haven't seen anything to suggest it's ever impossible. I've tried lots of combinations.

Comment: @Ben. Cool. If it works for you then I think you have your solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of red dots (N) is equal to the number of blue dots (from pictures seems so), a quite naive solution can be:

1. calculate the length of all possible links between all pairs blueDot-redDot (time complexity O(N^2));
2. sort links by increasing distance (O(Nlog(N)));
3. until there are bluePoint still not selected:

   1. extract the shorter link;
   2. Check if the associated bluePoint and redPoint has already been involved in others links (O(1) if you store flags in arrays indexed by point IDs):
   3. if yes: discard the link;
   4. if no: connect the points and flag them as selected.

Probably there can be some optimization, but this is anyway an iterative O(N^2) solution: much better than a brute force solution that, for example, use backtracking to explore all possibilities and find the right one.

Comment: Thanks Davide, really sorry but that's gone a little over my head. Can you clarify a few things regarding your points. #1 - Do you mean calculate every possible combination of lines between red and blue dots? (surely that's too many) #3 - What do you mean "until there are bluePoint still not selected"?

Comment: #1Yes. there are N*N=N^2 combinations. This is probably the step that can be optimized using some sort of heuristics, but I don't know how to do it. #3 this means "until there are bluePoints that are still not linked to redPoints".; if all blue points are selected, also all redPoints are, so you have terminated.

Comment: I thought the number of possible combinations was N! (factorial ), is that not the case?

Comment: Thinking about it, the number of possible lines or line lengths is N^2, but the number of combinations, as order matters, is N!. I think I've manage to implement what you suggested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bk7wkwg/) It makes things better, but it doesn't always preventing overlaps unfortunately.